# insertion/add method for a Binary Tree

Tags: java, binary-tree, nodes, binary-search, insertion

I need help implementing a simple website structure in text form based on a Binary Tree - each new "page" has a parent node and two children. Starting from the home the design is that the first "page" is added to the left hand node and then subsequent pages with home as the parent are added to the right node of that etc. all also linking to home as the parent. Same for sub categories - ie adding a page with parent "shops" should searh down the left until it finds shops page then add to the left if its the first to be added the right from that node for subsequent pages with the same parent.

Here's the code so far for node, site and page classes. I'm pretty sure my problem lies with non-recursiveness of the addpage methd as so far running the code produces a home page with two child nodes of shops & news but then all other nodes are null. Also reall news should be being added to the right node of shops rather than ome but I'm a bit stumped as to how to do that....

```
public class Site
{

public class PageNode
{

    private Page page;
    private PageNode firstchild;
    private PageNode parent;
    private PageNode nextsibling;

public PageNode()
{
    this.firstchild = null;
    this.parent = null;
    this.nextsibling = null;
}

public PageNode(String PageName)
{
    this.firstchild = null;
    this.parent = null;
    this.nextsibling = null;
}

public String toString()
{
    return ""+page;
}

}
private PageNode currentPage;
private PageNode homePage;

public Site()
{
    this.homePage=new PageNode();
    this.homePage.page=new Page("Home");
    this.currentPage=this.homePage;

    PageNode shops=addPage("Shops",this.homePage);
    addPage("News",this.homePage);
    PageNode products=addPage("Products",this.homePage);

    addPage("Paisley",shops);
    addPage("Hamilton",shops);

    PageNode kitchen=addPage("Kitchen",products);
    addPage("Bedroom",products);

    addPage("Kettles",kitchen);
    addPage("Cookers",kitchen);
    addPage("Toasters",kitchen);
}

public PageNode addPage(String PageName)
{
            this.currentPage=new PageNode();
            this.currentPage.page=new Page(PageName);

    PageNode ParentNode=new PageNode();
    ParentNode.page=currentPage.page;
    if (this.homePage==null)
        this.homePage=ParentNode;
    else
        ParentNode=this.addPage(PageName,ParentNode);
    return ParentNode;
}
private PageNode addPage(String PageName, PageNode ParentNode)
{
            ParentNode = new PageNode();
            ParentNode.page=new Page(PageName);

    if (this.currentPage.page.compareTo(ParentNode.page)==0)
    {
        System.out.println("attempt to insert a duplicate");
    }
    else
                    if (ParentNode.page.compareTo(currentPage.page)<0)

                        if(currentPage.firstchild == null)
                        {
            currentPage.firstchild=ParentNode;
                            ParentNode.firstchild = new PageNode();
                            ParentNode.firstchild.page = new Page(PageName);
                        }
                            else if(currentPage.nextsibling == null)
                            {
                                currentPage.nextsibling=ParentNode;                        
                                ParentNode.nextsibling = new PageNode();
                                ParentNode.nextsibling.page = new Page(PageName);
                            }
            return ParentNode;
}

public void displayCurrentPage()
{
                if (this.homePage!=null)
    {
        this.displayBranches(this.homePage);
    }
    else
        System.out.println("tree is empty");
    }
    private void displayBranches(PageNode ParentNode)
    {
    if (ParentNode!=null)
    {
        System.out.println(ParentNode.page+"  ");
        System.out.print("    left:  ");
        if (ParentNode.firstchild!=null)
            System.out.println(ParentNode.firstchild.page);
        else
            System.out.println("null");
        System.out.print("    right: ");
        if (ParentNode.nextsibling!=null)
            System.out.println(ParentNode.nextsibling.page);
        else
            System.out.println("null");
                    displayBranches(ParentNode.firstchild);
        displayBranches(ParentNode.nextsibling);
    }
}
```

and page class

```
public class Page implements Comparable
{
private String page;

public Page (String PageName)
{
    page = PageName;
}

public String getPage()
{
    return page;
}

public int compareTo(Object otherObject)
{
int result=((Page)otherObject).page.compareTo(this.page);
return result;
}
public String toString()
{
    return ""+page;
}
}
```

Please note - public Site() was implemented by tutor so rest needs to conform to the addpage calls therein.

Comment: I'm stumped as to how to modify my addpage method to correctly add the 10 pages. Ive tried alot of permuations but this is the best I've got without crashing it or casuing a stackioverflow from an infinite recursion :( Just an indicator of what might need altering would be a help. Thanks.

Comment: I have just discovered that I've basically been asked to implement this as a Left Child- Right Sibling Tree (not that the tutor thought it useful to say this but hey)...

Comment: Well - my prog is now adding Shops to left of home and News to right, then its (for some reason) adding Shops again to the left of shops and News to right of news - I've edited the above to shows the new code

Answer (score 0):

you'll want a *directory* tree not a binary search tree

this will be more clear if you structure your node like so

```
public class PageNode
{
    private Page page;
    private PageNode child;
    private PageNode parent;
    private PageNode nextSibling;

    //...
}
```

Comment: I see how renaming the nodes will help with clarity - but I think given what I've seen about Directory Tree structures (although the case study resembles one) I think the idea behind this is to implement it as a Binary Tree mimicking a directory tree...

Comment: the compare function then has to be modified to return -1 for a descendant of the current node and +1 for a descendant of a sibling

Comment: I'm guessing I need to compare "parent" values? But how do you do this in Page class? Should I override compareto in PageNode instead?